# Laravel 5.4: Advanced pivot table query issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have two models: `Order` and `Department`, joined by a many-to-many relationship. The pivot table on this relationship contains a "status" field. So a particular order may look something like:

- Manufacturing: completed
- Packaging: (not needed / not attached)
- Shipping: in progress

In the UI for my app I have a tab for each department and checkboxes for statuses. So the API needs to be able to take a request with one department and multiple possible statuses and return all orders which match one of the selected statuses for the given department.

Example query: `/api/orders?dep=manufacturing&statuses=notStarted,inProgress`

This needs to return all orders which are ***either*** "not started" or "in progress" for the manufacturing department (regardless of status in any other department)

Here is the query I wrote:

```
$query = Order::with("departments");
$department = Request::get('department');
$statuses = explode(",", Request::get('statuses', ""));

if (!empty($department))
{
    $query->whereHas('departments', function ($q) use ($department)
    {
        $q->where('name', $department);
    });
    if (count($statuses) > 0)
    {
        $query->where(function ($q) use ($department, $statuses)
        {
            foreach ($statuses as $status)
            {
                $q->orWhereHas('departments', function ($q) use ($department, $status)
                {
                    $q->where('name', $department)->wherePivot('status', $status);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

return $query->paginate(15);
```

This is throwing the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pivot' in 'where clause'
```

My relationship is defined as follows:

```
public function departments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Department', 'order_statuses')->using('App\Models\OrderStatus')->withPivot('status')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately came up with the following solution to this:

```
if (!empty($departments)
{
    if (count($statuses) > 0)
    {
        $query->whereHas('departments', function ($q) use ($department, $statuses)
        {
            $q->where('name', $department)->whereIn('order_statuses.status', $statuses);
        }
    } else {
        $query->whereHas('departments', function ($q) use ($department)
        {
            $q->where('name', $department);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, only the model keys will be present on the pivot object. If your pivot table contains extra attributes, you must specify them when defining the relationship:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withPivot('column1', 'column2');
```

Comment: My relationship was defined using `withPivot`. I'll update my original post with the entire relationship definition